# How to get all of the keys for Struts 2 form when using iterator

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator, ognl

I have the following code block in my JSP using Struts2 (which is inside a table which is in a form):

```
<s:iterator value="editableService.parameters"
status="serviceStatus">
<tr>
    <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
    <td><s:textfield name="value" label="Value" size="40" /></td>
</tr>

</s:iterator>
```

In my Struts2 action, how do I get all of the keys and their values when the user submits? Since the contents of this form are dynamic per iterator, I cant have single POJO represent form contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do, you need to write the code which is

**In action:**

```
private List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> getValues(){
  return values;
}
```

**In JSP:**

```
<s:iterator value="editableService.parameters" status="serviceStatus">
 <tr>
  <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
  <td><s:textfield name="values[%{#serviceStatus.index}]" value="%{value}" label="Value" size="40" /></td>
 </tr>
</s:iterator>
```